# MYSQLI Error, Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

I'm getting the Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

```
include 'connection.php';
// Create connection

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query_user = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Benutzername='".$benutzername."' AND Passwort='".$passwort."'";


if ($result = $mysqli->query($query_user)) {
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;  
}
```

It says my error is on the line `if ($result = $mysqli->query($query_user)) {`

Comment: I don't know PHP. Is it not should be `==` in `if` instead of `=` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That is an assignment `=` inside an `if ()` condition, not an equality test.

Comment: OK we use same in C also. Thanks!

Comment: The error means that `mysqli_connect()` failed. When the connect fails, you should exit after printing the error.

Comment: **Before you post a question asking “How do I solve this error?" do a search in the search box for the actual error message.**  There you will probably find other questions from people who have had the exact same problem, and then you can learn how they solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

to:

```
if (!$mysqli) {
    die ("Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

so that the script exits when there's a connect error. Otherwise, you'll print the error message and then continue as if everything were OK.